# Why does the button needs to be clicked twice to work

Tags: java, android, button

I have created this app I which there is a button, everything in the application is fine, except for the fact that if I want the button to work I have to press it twice, not once like suppose to be.
Here the piece of code:

```
//CODE:
public void INCASEOFCLICK(View view) {
    Button B = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B);
    B.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText A = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.A);
            TextView C = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.C);
            String AA=A.getText().toString();
            if(A.length()>0){
                C.setText(AA);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TRY AGAIN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: `INCASEOFCLICK` is already the onClickListener for your Button.

Comment: This is far from recommended methods of onClickListeners. first you have a click listener `INCASEOFCLICK` and then inside it you again `setOnClickListener` to the button. this is not how it should be done,  please refer to official documentation or good tutorials online.

Comment: move all the logic you have inside the inner onClick inside `INCASEOFCLICK`

Comment: I did another OnClickListener because when I leave only one, the ClickListner works only once.

Comment: that is because your definition/instantiation to `Button B` is wrong. once you click on it you are instantiating it again which then does not have any clicklistener assigned. refer to @AndroidWarrior's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is on the first click you are setting the clicklistener and on the second click you are getting the response. Usually if your write the below mentioned code inside `onCreate()` your button will work as expected.

```
Button B = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B);
B.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText A = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.A);
            TextView C = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.C);
            String AA=A.getText().toString();
            if(A.length()>0){
                C.setText(AA);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TRY AGAIN",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @user3775508 Just copy the above code inside your `onCreate()` method and remove all other code related to your button and it should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks. It worked, well not with the onCreate() but just removing line 4,5,6. Thanks